# Foreign key field not rendering in serializers django

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to show up the foreign key fields name instead of object id but not able to get through it. Tried using the related_name and then binding that to the serializer but still no luck,

**models.py**

```
class Employee(base_models.BaseDateModel):
    """
    DB model to store employee data
    """
   
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    level = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=LEVEL_CHOICES, default=L1)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} - {self.get_level_display()}'


class Room(base_models.BaseDateModel):
    """
    DB model to store available rooms in the building
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'


class Seat(base_models.BaseDateModel):
    """
    DB model to store available seats in a given room
    """
    room = models.ForeignKey('seating.Room', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.room} - {self.id}'


class EmployeeSeating(base_models.BaseDateModel):
    """
    DB model to store the seating details of any employee
    """
    name = models.ForeignKey('seating.Employee', on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='emp_name')
    room = models.ForeignKey('seating.ROOM', on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='emp_room')
    seat = models.ForeignKey('seating.SEAT', on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='emp_seat')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} - {self.room} - {self.seat}'
```

**serializers.py**

```
class EmployeeSeatingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    emp_name = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    emp_room = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    emp_seat = serializers.StringRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeSeating
        fields = ('id', 'emp_name', 'emp_room', 'emp_seat')
```

**views.py**

```
def listemp_api(request, pk=None):

    """
    Method to return the list of employee in a given room
    """

    if request.method == 'GET':

        room_id = pk
        if room_id:
            employee_data = EmployeeSeating.objects.filter(room_id = room_id)
       
            serializer = EmployeeSeatingSerializer(employee_data, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            employee_data = EmployeeSeating.objects.all()
            print(employee_data)
            serializer = EmployeeSeatingSerializer(employee_data, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

The result of the queryset using my view is as below

```
[
    {
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 5
    }
]
```

but I want the room, seat and other serialized fields that I added using stringfield but not able to achieve that.
Using `fields = '__all__'` gives me object number but misses out the additional fields I want ie. emp_room, emp_name etc

Answer (score 0):

Before moving on, I want to explain that the `related_name` field is used if you want to access `EmployeeSeating` model from `Employee` model. But, `EmployeeSeatingSerializer` is doing the opposite.
Secondly, in the `EmployeeSeating` model foreign keys, I think you should consider renaming `seating.ROOM` to `seating.Room` (if it's not working) and the same for `seating.SEAT`. Make sure from django admin panel if foreign keys are linked properly, otherwise, nothing will work.

Make sure to do `makemigrations` and `migrate` after making changes in database.

First, just try this on `name` field of the serializer. Remove other fields.

1. Create a model serializer for the `Employee` model, say `EmployeeSerializer`. Only give the field which you want to show, which in this case is the `name` field.
2. In your `EmployeeSeatingSerializer`, change `emp_name` field to the field which is used to refer to `Employee` model, which is `name` in this case. Do the same for other fields as well.
3. Change `emp_name = serializers.StringRelatedField()` to `name = EmployeeSerializer()`. Do the same for other fields.

Give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Employee(base_models.BaseDateModel):
"""
DB model to store employee data
"""

name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
level = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=LEVEL_CHOICES, default=L1)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.name} - {self.get_level_display()}'


class Room(base_models.BaseDateModel):
"""
DB model to store available rooms in the building
"""
name = models.CharField(max_length=15)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.name}'


class Seat(base_models.BaseDateModel):
"""
DB model to store available seats in a given room
"""
room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.room} - {self.id}'


class EmployeeSeating(base_models.BaseDateModel):
"""
DB model to store the seating details of any employee
"""
name = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='emp_name')
room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='emp_room')
seat = models.ForeignKey(Seat, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='emp_seat')

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.name} - {self.room} - {self.seat}'
```

Comment: Thanks but this didn't help, looks you changed the relative model name. Django does support something like this in model 
name = models.ForeignKey('seating.Employee', on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='emp_name')